# Order $n$ elements of infinite groups of finite exponent $n>2$

Tags: group-theory

I want to show or to disprove the following result:

> If $G$ is an infinite group, $n$ the exponent of $G$ is finite, $n>2$, then there are infinitely many elements of order $n$ and infinitely many elements of order less than $n$.

(Clearly this fails when $n=2$ as only the identity $e$ has order $\ne2$.)

The first part I think can be shown thus: if there are finitely many elements of order $n$, say $a_1,\dots,a_n$, then $b=a_1\cdots a_n a_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots a_1^{-1}$ has order $n$, but I'm not sure how to show that $b$ is distinct from $a_1,\dots,a_n$ (and $b\ne e$). I'm also not very sure on how to start the proof of the second part, if it is true at all.

Comment: The exponent of $G$ is the least $n$ such that $g^n=e$ for all $g$. So every element has order dividing $n$... So are you asking if there are always infinitely many elements of order $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always infinitely many elements with order $n$, and as I point out in the comments it is trivial that every elements order divides the exponent of the group:

Let $G$ be a group of exponent $n$ with finitely many elements of order $n$, say $g_1,...,g_m$ is an enumeration of the elements. Note that the set of order $n$ elements are closed under conjugation, any conjugation gives a permutation of $1,...,m$ by how conjugation acts on the labels of the $g_i$. Well there are only finitely many permutations of $1,...,m$. Suppose for now there are infinitely many elements in $G$, then for infinitely many $h_i \in G$ we get conjugation by $h_i$ corresponds to the same permutation, and we also get that conjugation by $h_i h_j ^{-1}$ corresponds to the identity permutation, hence $h_i h_j ^{-1}$ commute with all $g_i$. Note there are infinitely many distinct $h_ih_j^{-1}$, and so $g_1 h_i h_j^{-1}$ can not be a $g_k$ for infinitely many $(i,j)$, but $g_1 h_i h_j^{-1}$ has order $n$ for infinitely many $(i,j)$, so we reach a contradiction, and we must actually have infinitely many elements of order $n$.

Comment: This is true, I was confused about the part about "order not dividing $n$". Now I see that I don't actually need that part, and your proof is exactly what I need to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a gap in my argument as I am assuming there is at least one element of order $n$, but apriori it could be that maybe there are only elements of order 2,3, so the exponent would be 6. I will think about it some more and see if it can be fixed, and put more detailed clear proof later. @Marc

Comment: @Marc My answer is flawed, could you unaccept it so I can delete it? (It assumes there are elements of order equal to the exponent, and the last part about infinitely many $g_1h_ih_j^{-1}$ of order $n$ is not as clear as I thought it was when writing it)

Answer (score 1):

For any $n>2$ the direct product $\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}Z_n$ where $Z_n$ denotes the cyclic group of order $n$ has all elements of order dividing $n$; in particular it has infinitely many elements of order $n$ and none of order not dividing $n$.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question this is a counterexample to the claim.

Comment: It is, but $n$ must be prime.

Comment: Why does $n$ have to be prime? (I think I must be misunderstanding the problem if $n$ has to be prime) @NoamD.Elkies

Comment: sorry, I retract the comment: I misread the problem as asking for elements of exponent not *equal* to $n$, but in fact it says not *dividing* $n$.

Comment: @NoamDElkies It was my question that was incorrect. But now I see that this example with $n$ prime does provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

A [Tarski Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) is a counterexample for every prime $\;p>10^{75}\;$ .

Comment: That is serious overkill!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I think it is a rather easy reachable one for every one who's come across these astonishing groups.